# Why do “Unsecure connection” warnings in modern browsers don’t work against SSL Strip?

Tags: browser-hijacking, safe-browsing-filter

Why do “Unsecure connection” warnings in modern browsers don’t work against SSL
Strip?

Comment: May be this one can help you [http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work][1]


  [1]: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work

Answer (score 1):

You should watch Moxie Marlinspike's talk [Defeating SSL using SSLStrip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFol6IMbZ7Y). In short SSLStrip is a type of MITM attack that forces a victim's browser into communicating with an adversary in plain-text over HTTP, and the adversary proxies the modified content from an HTTPS server. To do this, SSLStrip is "stripping"  https:// URLs and turning them into http:// URLs.

[HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is a proposed solution to this problem.

Answer From [How does SSLstrip work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work)