# sslstrip showing an error

Tags: sslstrip

What should i do to get through https?

I don't know whether sslstrip working or not.

```
sslstrip -l 8080 

/usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/OpenSSL/crypto.py:12: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.

sslstrip 0.9 by Moxie Marlinspike running...
```

Comment: Why do you think it should work, based on the error message you get?

Comment: actually my question is what should i do to get through https 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does SSLstrip work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work)